# Rewriting to same log file each time in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a product using which I run my application(which I have written). It is a multithreaded application which access one single log file. I am facing the problem that each time I start my application log file is getting appended. Only when I restart the product then fresh log file is created. But I want each time my application is running I want only fresh content in my log file.

Below is the code.

```
//Log4j initialization
public void initLog4j() throws MyException {

    if (logfile != null ){
        myLog4j = Logger.getLogger("MY_LOG");           
        try {
            appender = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout("%m%n"),logfile.getAbsolutePath(),false);
            appender.setAppend(false);
            myLog4j.addAppender(appender);
            myLog4j.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MyException(104, logfile.getAbsolutePath());
        }           

    }

//Stopping to write to log4j
public void stop() {        
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");        
    writeToLog4j(INFO,new StringBuilder(name).append(" stop: ").append(dateFormat.format(new Date())).toString(),true);
}
```

What I tried till now is I tried deleting the file but it was not deleting as FileDescriptor was not released. So I added following code in stop() function

```
if(null != appender) {
        appender.close();
    }
```

After this new File is getting generated or existing file is overwritten. But each time my application is run I am having below message each time I try writing to logfile

log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [null].

Please somebody help me in solving this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you configure log4j programmatically?

Comment: No specific reason. I found it easy. I don't know much about properties file and how to use them in log4j. Wih properties file this can be solved?? If yes how?

Comment: It is still not really clear when exactly a new logfile is created. What is the difference between "when I restart the product" and "each time my application is running" ...

Comment: I have a plugin product for which I wrote one plugin. Now I am testing my plugin. To run my application I need to start the plugin product. If this plug in product is restarted every time new log file is created. But not when I just run my plugin(application)

Comment: Did you init a new appender after calling close() and added it to myLog4j? Also, you should remove the appender after you close it, I guess. Not really sure, therefore comment, not answer.

Comment: each time my plug in runs initLog4j() function is called. There I am creating new FileApender always. I am not removing appender anywhere. I will try that as well

Comment: Thank you. You are right. If we remove the appender after we close the appender then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have to remove the appender after closing it. 
It seems log4j will not do this automatically.